# Pick out the countable sets from the following

Tags: real-analysis

Pick out the countable sets from the following:
a. {$\alpha ∈\mathbb{R}$ : $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients}.
b. The complement in $\mathbb{R}$ of the set described in statement (a) above.
c. The set of all points in the plane whose coordinates are rational.
d. Any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose Lebesgue measure is zero.

---

(a) it is the set of all algebraic numbers and hence countable.

(b) it is the set of all transcendental numbers and hence uncountable.
(c) it is countable.
(d) cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero.it is uncountable.

am I correct?

Comment: Looks good to me! I'm not sure how much justification you need, though.

Comment: you are absolutely correct